# How do I convert each of the words to a number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read a file and overwrite its contents with numbers. That means for the first word it would be 1, for the second word it would be 2, and so on.

*This is my code:*

```
 file=open("reviews.txt","r+")
i=1
for x in file:
    line=file.readline()
    word=line.split()
    file.write(word.replace(word,str(i)))
    i+=1
file.close()
```

*Input file:*

```
This movie is not so good

This movie is good
```

*Expected output file:*

```
1 2 3 4 5 6

7 8 9 10
```

During compilation time I keep getting an error that: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`. Which one is the list object? All the variables are strings as far as I know. Please help me.

Comment: Word is an array, You need to iterate over it

Comment: Strings may also be regarded as lists of characters

Comment: `line.split` returns a list [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be OK to first create the output, with any method that you like, then write it once in the file. Maybe, `file.write` in the loop wouldn't be so necessary.

#### Steps

- We open the file, get all its content, and close it.
- Using `re` module in `DOTALL` mode, we'd get anything that we want to replace in the first capturing group, in this case, with `(\S+)` or `(\w+)` etc., then we collect all other chars in the second capturing group with `(.+?)`, then with `re.findall`, we'd generate two-elements tuples in a list, which we'd want to replace the first element of those tuples.
- We then write a loop, and replace the first group with an incrementing counter, which is the idea here, and the second group untouched, and we would stepwise concat both as our new content to `string_out`
- We finally open the [empty] file, and write the `string_out`, and close it.

#### Test

```
import re

file = open("reviews.txt","r+")
word_finder, counter, string_out = re.findall(r"(\S+)|(.+?)", file.read(), re.DOTALL), 0, ''
file.close()

for item in word_finder:
    if item[0]:
        counter += 1
        string_out += str(counter)
    else:
        string_out += item[1]

try:
    file = open("reviews.txt","w")
    file.write(string_out)
finally:
    file.close()
```

#### Output

```
1 2 3 4 5 6

7 8 9 10
```

#### RegEx

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hIeS9k/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/hIeS9k/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### Reference

[re — Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: What is `re` ? I couldn't quite understand your code.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `split` is returning a list, which you need to iterate to handle the replacement of each word:

```
with open("reviews.txt", "r+") as file:
    i = 1
    line = file.readline()
    while line:
        words = line.split()
        for item in words:
            file.write(str(i) + ' ')
            i += 1
        line = file.readline()

    file.close()
```

Comment: You want to increment `i` inside the inner loop, I think.

Comment: The words don't get replaced by the numbers, they just get appended to the EOF.